# creating a structure to store student information and grades, and calculate mean and grade of each student and the mean and standard deviation in C++

Tags: c++, structure, user-defined-functions, mean, standard-deviation

I'm working on answering the following question
Create a structure representing a student object with the following members

```
regno.
courseid
unitsRegistered: This should be an array of the course units you registered to capture marks
unitsmarks: This should be an array to store the marks for the units registered. Find a way to relate the two.
firstname
surname
address
```

By using the structure above, write a program that populates the details of a student and compute the average, and the grade as well as the total marks. This task should be accomplished by writing functions for `getData()` - to populate the structure, `printStudent()` - to display the detail of the student, `computeGrade()` - to compute the grade of the student and `computeMean()` that computes the mean of the students: Pass the appropriate data

NB: The function `getData()` - is a subroutine and uses structure as a reference - input, same concept to printData()

Consider that your class has 10 students. Compute the class mean and standard deviation, highest class mark and lowest class mark

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_UNITS = 3;
const int NUM_STUDENTS = 10;

struct Student {
    int regno;
    int courseid;
    int unitsRegistered[MAX_UNITS];
    int unitsmarks[MAX_UNITS];
    string firstname;
    string surname;
    string address;
};

void getData(Student& s) {
    cout << "Enter the following details for the student:" << endl;
    cout << "Registration Number: ";
    cin >> s.regno;
    cout << "Course ID: ";
    cin >> s.courseid;
    cout << "First Name: ";
    cin >> s.firstname;
    cout << "Surname: ";
    cin >> s.surname;
    cout << "Address: ";
    cin >> s.address;

    cout << "Enter marks for " << MAX_UNITS << " course units:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_UNITS; i++) {
        cout << "Unit " << i+1 << " marks: ";
        cin >> s.unitsmarks[i];
        cout << "Units " << i+1 << " registered: ";
        cin >> s.unitsRegistered[i];
    }
}

void printStudent(const Student& s) {
    cout << "Registration Number: " << s.regno << endl;
    cout << "Course ID: " << s.courseid << endl;
    cout << "First Name: " << s.firstname << endl;
    cout << "Surname: " << s.surname << endl;
    cout << "Address: " << s.address << endl;
    cout << "Units Registered: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_UNITS; i++) {
        cout << s.unitsRegistered[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Units Marks: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_UNITS; i++) {
        cout << s.unitsmarks[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

double computeMean(const Student& s) {
    double sum = 0;
    double totalUnits = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_UNITS; i++) {
        if (s.unitsmarks[i] > 0) {
            sum += s.unitsmarks[i] * s.unitsRegistered[i];
            totalUnits += s.unitsRegistered[i];
        }
    }
    return sum / totalUnits;
}

char computeGrade(double mean) {
    if (mean >= 70) {
        return 'A';
    } else if (mean >= 60) {
        return 'B';
    } else if (mean >= 50) {
        return 'C';
    } else if (mean >= 40) {
        return 'D';
    } else {
        return 'F';
    }
}

int main() {
    Student students[NUM_STUDENTS];

    // Populate student details
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STUDENTS; i++) {
        getData(students[i]);
        cout << endl;
    }

    // Print student details and compute grade and mean
    double classSum = 0;
    double classSumSquared = 0;
    double classMean = 0;
    double classStdDev = 0;
    double highestMark = 0;
    double lowestMark = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STUDENTS; i++) {
        printStudent(students[i]);
        double mean = computeMean(students[i]);
        char grade = computeGrade(mean);
        cout << "Mean:";}}
```

this is the code i wrote. However< I'm unable to calculate mean, standard deviation and grades. what correct program can I use

Comment: I like your grading system.  Usually 90 to 100% is an `A`, and less than 50% is `F`.

Comment: *"I'm unable to calculate mean"*, then have a look at the function `computeMean()`.

Comment: To *print* the `mean`, in your `for` loop, use this:  `cout << "Mean: " << mean << "\n";`.

Comment: I highly recommend stepping through your program with a *debugger*.  You'll be able to see how it really functions or operates.